# PHP get content wrapped inside quotes

Tags: php

I have following:

```
$content = "[item title='Title1'][item title='Title2']";
```

I want to get all the titles which are between single quotes (From above, Title1 and Title2).

I am trying following, but does not work:

```
preg_match_all( '/item title="([^\']+)"/i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: you used double quota for matching? check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes with escape `\'`

```
preg_match_all( '/item title=\'([^\']+)\'/i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
                              ^         ^ here
```

Catch with single quotes `'` or double quotes `"`

```
preg_match_all( '/item title=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]/i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

Comment: why that? can't you enclose the pattern with double quota?!

Comment: @Akam Why not? Check my answer

Comment: just use `"/item title='([^']+)'/i"`